# EF6 - using Contains with a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a list of `Ingredients`.

In my database, each `Recipe` has a list of `Ingredients` (many to many).

Given a list of `Ingredients`, I'm trying to find all `Recipes` whose list of `Ingredients` is contained within the ingredients passed in.

For example:  If I pass in `ingredients = [Bananas, Bread]` only:

```
Banana Sandwich: Bananas, Bread
Banana PB Sandwich: Bananas, Bread, PB
```

I want to run a query like `db.Recipes.Where(e => ingredients.Contains(e.Ingredients))`

Returning only Banana Sandwich in the above example.  `Contains` does not accept an IEnumerable though.  What can I do to achieve this query without loading all Recipes into memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax to use the All() would be to use

```
var recipes = db.Recipes
    .Where(r => r.Ingredients.All(i => ingredients.Contains(i.PropertyNameToMatch));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `All`, but I'm not 100% sure LINQ to Entities supports that.

```
db.Receipes.Where(e => e.Ingredients.All(ingredients.Contains));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` does not accept `IEnumerable`, but it accepts `IQueryable`

Try defining your ingredients as `IQueryable` and see!